# Pattern for preventing a lot of if else

Tags: php, design-patterns

please provide some example or pattern name to avoid a lot of `if` `else` constructions. Maybe some design  pattern exists for more clean and readable code?

```
public function process(CreditNotificationInterface $obj)
{
    $this->creditNotification = $obj;
    if ($obj->isAccepted()) {
        return $this->accept();
    } else {
        if ($obj->isDeclined()) {
            return $this->decline();
        } else {
            if ($obj->isError()) {
                return $this->error();
            } else {
                if ($obj->isAbandoned()) {
                    return $this->abandoned();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `switch`? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: well, better describe your problem nd give your example code that is too long. then it is a lot easier to help

Comment: You could sometimes if you use the combination of `&&` and `||` nicely

Comment: look at the [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: Might also try looking at early returns.

Comment: i provide example above

Comment: https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use design pattern strategy pattern looks to me like best solver for lot of if/else's. http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html

Answer (score 0):

The `switch` statement was conceived to solve exactly this problem. It allows you to check values serially in an attempt to reduce nested ifs and condense serial if-elses. Take a look here for examples on how to apply the `switch` statement in PHP. Then apply it to your problem.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp